# Fetch Api - Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I want to throw result.data in users.

```
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((result) => {
    this.setState({
      users: result.data,
    });
  });

const UsersAPI = {
  users: [],
};

console.log(UsersAPI.users);

export default UsersAPI;
```

I want to show API data on console.
My page has no other code.

About.js

```
import UsersAPI from '../UserApi';
export default class About extends Component {
render() {
   console.log(UsersApi.users)
   return ( <div> </div>
      )
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file only contains this set of code it won't work make these changes to make it work.

```
 fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then((result) => {
     UsersAPI.users.push(result.data)
     console.log(UsersAPI.users);
 });

 const UsersAPI = {
     users: [],
 };


 export default UsersAPI;
```

Comment: working thank you. [link](https://i.ibb.co/StdJw0p/image.png) console.log(UsersApi.users) its show. console.log(UsersApi.users.[0]) not working, how can fix it. Thank you.

Comment: i have updated the code check that out, that was happening because of javascript async behavior.

Comment: Update code. I'm transferring the data on this page to about us.